# What does it mean for operators to couple?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, linear-algebra

I was reading on Quantum Ising Model and I came across this notion. suppose there are N sites and each site has some operators, say the Pauli matrices $\sigma_1^z, \sigma_2^z$, etc. These two matrices are to commute with one another. Suppose we are working on a basis where each of these matrices are diagonal. What does it mean to multiply two matrices at different sites?

Say $N = 2$, What does $\sigma_1^z$ look like in the full 4-dimensional Hilbert space? Does it look like
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 1&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  -1&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$$ or $$\begin{bmatrix}
 1&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  -1&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  1& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& 1
\end{bmatrix}?$$
If it is former then the product of $\sigma_1^z$ and $\sigma_2^z$ should be zero and if it is latter it should be $\sigma_1^z \oplus \sigma_2^z$. The resourse I am reading simply says that these two operators are coupled without saying what it means mathematically.

Also, people seem to add, subtract and multiply operators that act on different spaces. What does it mean to do these kind of operations? Thank you!

Comment: If you have a bipartite quantum system $H=H_1 \otimes H_2$ and operators $A_1$ on $H_1$ and $A_2$ on $H_2$, then $A_1\otimes\mathbb I_2$ and $\mathbb I_1 \otimes A_2$ are the operators lifted from $H_1$ and $H_2$ to $H$, respectively. We find $(A_1\otimes\mathbb I_2) \, (\mathbb I_1 \otimes A_2)=A_1\otimes A_2$. Does this help? If you're not familiar with the notion of tensor products / operator of tensor products, I'd advice you to read this in some textbook on quantum mechanics. An answer to this question would need to explain, I guess, all of that. The question seems to broad IMHO.

Comment: Regarding your last question: Sometimes people omit the tensor product with the identity operator, i.e. they write $A_1$ instead of $A_1\otimes \mathbb I_2$, which is an abuse of notation. Maybe this causes the confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people in comments have already said, the Pauli matrices in the extended Hilbert space will be the tensor products of corresponding sub-operators:
$$\sigma^z_1=\sigma_z \otimes \mathbb{1},\;\,\sigma^z_1=\mathbb{1} \otimes \sigma_z$$
Here the first (second) operator always acts in the Hilbert sub-space of the first (second) spin. If you want an explicit matrix form, one representation can be as follows:
$$
\sigma_1^z = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

and
$$
\sigma_2^z = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Here you can think of the first operator acting such that it only "sees" the $2 \times 2$ blocks of the full matrix, while the second one operates "inside" those blocks. As an example take

$$
\sigma_x \otimes \sigma_z = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

You can apply this "nested" structure to the higher-order tensor products, but it will obviously quickly get out of hand.